# Count mismatch - while querying oracle database session & oracle through spark sql

Tags: oracle, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

This sounds really weird  , I have an oracle database , I am trying to make a select from an oracle database through spark sql , but the data I look for exits really in the database , but I cannot find it in the request launched from scala. so i tried to compute the number of exiting data

```
select count (*) from TMP_STRUCTURE
```

from oracle console I got `373799`

when I put

```
  val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("spark session example").getOrCreate()
  //connect to table TMP_STRUCTURE oracle
  val spark = sparkSession.sqlContext
  val df = spark.load("jdbc",
    Map("url" -> "jdbc:oracle:thin:IPTECH/IPTECH@//localhost:1521/XE",
      "dbtable" -> "TMP_STRUCTURE"))


    println(df.count())
373797
```

I cannot find why ?

Any help please .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite impossible as there might be 2 chances

- Case 1 : you might be reading uncommitted data from oracle session and through spark sql you might be reading committed dataset. (execute commit and check again)
- Case 2: from oracle session you might be connecting to different database having nearly same number of  rows. and might have used different database for spark sql
  (ensure/cross check both databases you tried to connect are same)